Django deployment. Apache, wsgi, python 3.12
Everything worked fine on python 3.8, but I need to update python to version 3.12. libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 apparently does not support version 3.12. After starting the server, I get the error module django not found. What should I do?)
<VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot /.../back/...
   <Directory /.../back/.../.../...>
     <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
     </Files>
   </Directory>
   <Directory /.../back/...>
     Require all granted
   </Directory>
   WSGIDaemonProcess ... lang='en_US.UTF-8' locale='en_US.UTF-8' python-path=/.../back/... python-home=/.../back/venv
   WSGIProcessGroup ...
   WSGIScriptAlias / /.../back/.../.../wsgi.py
   WSGIPassAuthorization On
   ServerName ...
   ServerAlias ...
   ErrorLog /.../back/logs/back-error.log
   CustomLog /.../back/logs/back-access.log combined
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile "..."
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "..."
   SSLCertificateChainFile "..."
</VirtualHost>


You should Downgrade your Django also, commonly the package is looking for equal support too,

But i want to upgrade from 3.8 to 3.12
